# Can't send mail in Lotus iNotes 8.5.2 in Firefox 15 and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: firefox, email, ubuntu-12.04, lotus-notes

Can't send mail in Lotus iNotes 8.5.2.

I'm running Firefox 15.0 in Linux Ubuntu 12.04.

When in 'Full mode' - Every other button works okay, such as 'New' or 'Reply' or 'Mark as' or 'Retention' but when I hit the 'Send' button, nothing happens.

When in 'Lite mode' or 'Ultra-light mode' the 'Send' button actually does send the email, but those mode's also have very limited functionality.

I'm seen some old issues regarding this with Firefox 4 no longer using XUL, so I added 'Remote XUL Manager 1.1.2' and added all of the possible corresponding domains, but that's not helping.

Some background: I did install Chrome and I can send emails in 'Full mode' but this is only an interim solution. I have a second computer running Ubuntu 12.04 and Firefox 15.0 and I also can't send emails in 'Full mode.'

Any help is appreciated!

(This post was copied from my original post in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496246/cant-send-mail-in-lotus-inotes-8-5-2-in-firefox-15-and-ubuntu-12-04 ... it seems that stackoverflow wasn't the right place for that sort of question)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  It's frowned upon posting the same question on multiple sites.  If the question is better suited for SuperUser, it will be migrated over from StackOverflow by some admins.  Looks like you have a couple suggestions there though.

Comment: Hi dangowans.  I forgot to flag the post for admin attention over on StackOverflow after commenting that it really belonged over here on SuperUser.  So the cross-post is more my fault than Otto's.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due to signed script being deprecated in Firefox 15.  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21610926  here is a technote.

Comment: So I came across that IBM web page also, however, I'll provide some backstory that makes me think that isn't necessarily the case. Another computer of mine is running OpenSuse 10.3 and Firefox 15 and yet a third Windows XP and Firefox 15, and currently I can send email in 'Full mode' in both. So, I would suppose that it isn't a server side setting if two computers can send email, and another cannot. I'm trying to think of what differences can there be that can cause this.

Comment: Edit -- the technote names two things -- 1) a setting at the server in notes.ini and 2) Firefox 15's different behavior.  I'm positting that the data points I have point to something else.  Hard to say...